# How to interact with a separate pop-up window/website with Selenium / Chrome Driver in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a process with Selenium, and am having troubles figuring out how to switch between open windows while the program is running.
After clicking on the button, it opens another website that has a separate url, which is *unique each time it is opened.* I need to switch Selenium from interacting with the original website to this new popup within the browser, caused by the original website. The new window shows that it is also controlled by Chromedriver with the bit at the top that says "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software." Additionally, the actual website opened will be the same, just the fine print after the '.com/' is different.
How would I go about doing this? Also, how would I switch back? (If this is even possible)

For example:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("https://originalwebsite.com/")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'buttons-xpath').click()
# (popup opens up now)
# *switch to popup website here*
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'button-on-new-website-xpath').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'second-button-on-new-website-xpath').click()
# *popup website closes*
# switch back to original website / window
```

Thanks!

I have tried to use driver.navigate in a variety of ways but generally have no clue what I am doing. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry but I am not able to recreate your problem. Can you add a screenshot here, please?

Comment: added an image so you can tell what I mean

Comment: check this website  [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/selenium_webdriver/selenium_webdriver_pop_ups.htm)

Comment: thank you. how would I assign the output of that to a list? sorry, I started with python yesterday haha

Comment: nevermind, I got it, thank you so much! How do I say you answered the question?

Comment: In comments, you can add a comment small arrow or triangle on the right side of the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from ALex Break led to the answer.
All I had to do was:

```py
handles = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(handles[x])
#handles[x] is the index of the list handles that has the handle I want to switch 
#to stored in it
```